# Emacs - Using perform-replace with counter

Tags: replace, emacs

I'm trying to write a command in elisp to automatically renumber unit tests in a given file.  In order to help me easily locate failing tests, I generally use the following syntax (using GoogleTest):

**TEST(testCaseName, T0XX_Test_Description)**

I've been able to write a working command using a while loop with re-search-forward / replace-match:

```
(defun renumber-tests-auto(&optional num)
 "Automatically renumber the tests from the current location in
 the active buffer. Optional argument sets the current test
 number (instead of 1).  This function automatically updates
 all test numbers from the current location until the end of
 the buffer without querying the user for each test."

  (interactive "NStarting test number: ")
  (save-excursion
  (setq num (or num 1 ))
  (while (re-search-forward ", +T0[0-9]+" nil t )
    (replace-match
      (concat ", T" (format "%03d" num )))
    (setq num (+ 1 num))
    )
  )
)
```

However, I'd also really like to have an interactive version of this function, using perform-replace to interactively query the user for each test.  I could, of course, simply handle the querying behaviour manually in my code, however, given that this functionality is already present, I don't really want to have to re-implement this.  Furthermore, I'd like to ensure that this command has the same interface as the other built-in query-replace functions.

My latest failed attempt follows:

```
(defun renumber-tests(&optional num)
  (interactive "NStarting test number: ")
  (save-excursion
    (setq num (or num 1 ))
    (perform-replace ", +T0[0-9]+"
                 (concat ", T" (format "%03d" (+ 1 num )
                                   ))
                 t t nil)
  )
)
```

However, this does not update the value of num each time it is run (I also tried (setq num (+ 1 num) ) and got the same result.

I'd greatly appreciate some help from those more experienced in elisp - if there's any way to make it work the way I am intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `perform-replace`with a `string`as replacement text. You must supply a replacement function to do dynamic replacement. Quote from documentation:

> REPLACEMENTS is either a string, a list of strings, or a cons cell
>   containing a function and its first argument.  The function is called
>   to generate each replacement like this:   (funcall (car replacements)
>   (cdr replacements) replace-count) It must return a string.

This way you can also get rid of mutation:

```lisp
(defun renumber-tests(&optional num)
  (interactive "NStarting test number: ")
  (save-excursion
    (perform-replace ", +T0[0-9]+"
             (list (lambda (replacement replace-count)
                 (concat ", T" (format "%03d" (+ replace-count (or num 1))))))
             t t nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that it needed to be some sort of lambda function, but I had no clue how to do this at all using lisp.  I've been working for years in c++ but only just now started dabbling casually in lisp...